# Example of zero symmetric part of near-ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

can you help me to find the example of zero symmetric of near ring?
A left near-ring N is called Zero symmetric
if 0x = 0 for all x element N

Comment: How about just a ring?

Comment: yes, ring is one of the example of zero symmetric..
but i need example of pure near-ring
i tried near ring of the set of function under addition and composition, but i can't find the zero symmetric

Comment: Then it has been solved

Comment: okay thank u very much

Comment: Do you mean a minimal near-ring? As in fullfilks only bare minimum of axioms?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a nonabelian group $G$ and let $N$ be the nearring of functions from $G$ into $G$ with pointwise addition and function composition as operations, you will be close.

The zero map already absorbs on the right ($0\circ f=0$) but not necessarily on the left. But it turns out that the subset $\{g\in N\mid g\circ 0=0\}$ is a subnearring of $N$ that *is* zero symmetric. Pick your favorite small nonabelian groups and see which ones yield a nontrivial subnearring of this type.